# CSS li item not showing correct in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a < ul > element with the following CSS class:

```
.css_admin_ul {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

There are 2 < li > elements with the following CSS:

```
.css_admin_li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The problem is that the elements show fine in IE8 and Firefox, but not in IE7.

The layout supposed to be like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|     CONTENT LI 1    |    CONTENT LI 2   |
-------------------------------------------
```

That's the case in IE8, Firefox and Safari, but in IE7 this shows up like:

```
-----------------------
|     CONTENT LI 1    |
-----------------------
|     CONTENT LI 2    |
-----------------------
```

So they are not in 1 line next to eachother.

Who knows what's causing this issue and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The css where the UL is in is:

```
.css_div_tabcontrol_content{
 padding: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inline-block` is [buggy in IE7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

I would advise you to use either `float:left;` as the simple solution (probably then applying `overflow:auto;` to the UL), or use `display: inline;` and some other property which confers the magical voodoo [hasLayout](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout) - traditionally `zoom:1` or a fixed height/width dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly,

```
display:inline;
```

should do the trick.

Or you could `float:left;` the `<UL>` and also `float:left;` all `<LI>s` within.

You can have a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgnkt/3/).

Answer (score 0):

you should make it such I think.

```
.css_admin_ul {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.css_admin_li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

there is no point in adding float: left; and display: block to the same element.

Comment: Ok when I do this it works in IE7 and IE8 but in IE8 the content which comes below the UL is rendered behind the content of the UL so how can I tell the content to start under the UL?

Comment: I've added the CSS where the UL comes in

Comment: No as I told earlier the UL renders correctly in IE7 but now the issue is in IE8